# Arrays from input file

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing

I am a very beginner for C++ and right now I need to process data from an input file which has loads of lines like the following:

> 2012019109 Proadan Legeaf Coaa Female 65

These are the student number, name (2 or 3 words), gender and test score.

I must create an array for each of these attributes. Also, I do not know how many lines the input file might contain (up to 100,000) but the first number within the input file will be the number of lines in that file.

Once I set up an array, I need to implement a function to sort the records by alphabetical string order (ascending) of Name and then put these into an output file.

I have tried doing to first part (setting up arrays) in the following way but it seems wrong:

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

fin.open("input.txt");
fout.open("output.txt");

if (fin.fail()) {
    cout << "Fail to open inout.txt" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int x; 
fin >> x; //this is the first number within the input text file, indicating the number of lines in the file. I would use this to determine the size of the arrays:

int UID [x];
string name [x];
string gender [x];
int score [x];

int y = 0;


// In the following part, I am trying to extract the information into the different arrays, one by one, increasing the number of the element from 0 up till x. Complier error says no matching function for call for the UID and score lines.

while (y!=x, y++) {
    getline(fin, UID [y], '\t');
    getline(fin, name [y], '\t');
    getline(fin, gender [y], '\t');
    getline(fin, score [y], '\t');
    break;
    }`
```

Once I have these arrays I would just need to find a way to order it alphabetically, but even with these first steps I am stuck. As you can probably tell, I do not know much about programming and would appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Thank you for your comments and help so far, I really appreciate your time. My problem is that as this is for a project work at school, I am required to use arrays (for some unexplicable reason).

FYI, In the input file, number/name/gender/score are separataed by TAB ('/t').

Is there any way to get around the above issues whilst sticking to the arrays and not using vectors or maps?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly. And do see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) maybe you want to use `getdelim`

Comment: In C++, you don't use arrays unless you really need them. You use `std::vector` or `std::list` instead. They're resizable and safe.

Comment: Also, note that the logic for the terminating condition of your while loop is incorrect. If an array has N items, the index of the last one is N-1. This is more or less what qPCR4vir is getting at. Also, you have no code yet to determine the number of tokens on a line. That is to say - if you count the number of space characters on the line(assuming correct input & a single space between items on each line), you'd be able to work out if the name was 2 or 3 words.

Comment: @enhzflep regarding the number of token per line, by looking at the existing code, I actually assume that maybe the data are actually separated by tabs and the name only contains spaces.

Comment: See my last edit for an answer to your last question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you are trying to read a string inside an int** :

```
getline(fin, UID [y], '\t');
```

UID[y] is an int while getline can only store into a string.

So you have to first store it in a buffer string and then convert it to an int using [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi) for instance :

```
string UID_buffer;
getline(fin, UID_buffer, '\t'); 
UID[y] = atoi(UID_buffer.c_str());
```

But there is another problem, your **UID are actually to big to fit inside a signed int**, you may try to store them in unsigned 32 or 64 bit, but it may be simpler just to store them as strings.

The [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) approach would suggest you to **use a class** to store each object instead of using multiple arrays :

```
struct Person {
    string UID;
    string name;
    string gender;
    int score;
};
```

And then **create only one array** :

```
Person* database = new Person[x];
```

You can also create a C++ re-sizable containers such as [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector), it would be much easier to sort it :

```
vector<Person> database;
```

Also note you should use a **for loop instead of while**.

For the loop code, you could use getline to read one line first, make a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream) out of it and use getline on this stream to read each element of the line, like this :

```
for(int y = 0, y < x; y++) {

    getline(fin, line); 
    stringstream linestream(line);

    Person newPerson;

    getline(linestream, newPerson.UID, '\t'); 
    getline(linestream, newPerson.name, '\t'); 
    getline(linestream, newPerson.gender, '\t'); 

    string buffer;
    getline(linestream, buffer, '\t'); 
    newPerson.score = atoi(buffer.c_str());

    database.push_back(newPerson);
}
```

To sort the vector you will obtain, you can use the [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort) algorithm from the STL, it uses the "<" operator of the class, so you just have to overload this operator and use sort on the vector.

```
sort(database.begin(), database.end());
```

With a comparison operator you defined like this :

```
bool operator< (const Person & p1, const Person& p2)
{
    //just an example
    return p1.UID.compare(p2.UID) < 0;
}
```

You can learn more about overloading operator [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/94-overloading-the-comparison-operators/).

**EDIT**

If you can't use vector, that doesn't really change the loop code (just replace newPerson by the corresponding already allocated Person object (something like database[x]).

Now for the sorting, you could still use the sort algorithm for the STL, it's supposed to work on iterators but it can work on pointers. It's not a neat solution and it's probably not what you're supposed to do.

Otherwise you can implement your own sorting algorithm, it's really a [textbook case](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/sequencing/sort-algorithms/).

Note that if you don't use a structure and keep using multiple arrays then you can't use the STL sorting algorithm and the data swap in your sorting algorithm would be much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, use:

```
for (int y=0 ; y<x, y++)
```

and not the `while`
But you can make your live a lot easer using vectors or maps.
I know, it is not a good idea to give you complete code. It is better if try self. But I want you to motivate to study the STL. It is realy easy.(you my find more eficient way)

For example:

```
int x; 
fin >> x; //this is the first number within ...    

std::multimap<std::string,std::string> rows;
std::string row;
while(getline(fin, row))
{
     std::stringstream r(row) ;
     std::string name;
     getline(row, name, '\t'); // ID
     getline(row, name, '\t'); // name
     rows.insert(std::make_pair(name,row));
}

fout << x << std::endl;
for (const auto& r : rows)
  fout << r << std::endl;

if (x!=rows.size())   
   //.... error?
```

No map? ...

```
struct row{string ID, name, rest;};
```

...

```
fout << x << std::endl;
row *rows=new row[x];
for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
{
    getline(fin, rows[i].ID,   '\t'); // ID
    getline(fin, rows[i].name, '\t'); // name
    getline(fin, rows[i].rest      ); 
}
  std::sort(rows,rows+x,[](const row& r1, const row& r2) 
                              {return r1.name<r2.name;}  );
  for( i=0;i<x;++i)
     fout<<rows[i].ID<<'\t'<< rows[i].name<<'\t'<< rows[i].rest<<endl;
```

No lambdas ? [Here a complete example](http://ideone.com/IQ7JB6)

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;
struct row{string ID, name, rest;};

bool operator < (const row& r1, const row& r2) 
{  return r1.name<r2.name;} 

ostream &operator<<(ostream&o, const row&r)
{  return o<<r.ID<<'\t'<< r.name<<'\t'<< r.rest<<endl; }  

int main()
{ int x=2;
  row rows[]={{"1","BB","r1"},{"2","AA","r2"}};//=new row[x];
  std::sort(rows,rows+x);
  for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
    cout<<rows[i]; 
}
```

[Or here:](http://ideone.com/mXlWcH) (I hope you dont simply copy the code, but go to [read the references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) and enjoy learning the use of the standard c++ library)

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>  
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;
struct row{string ID, name, rest;};

bool operator < (const row& r1, const row& r2) 
{  return r1.name<r2.name;} 

ostream &operator<<(ostream&o, const row&r)
{  return o<<r.ID<<'\t'<< r.name<<'\t'<< r.rest <<endl; }  

int main()
{ 
  stringstream fin,fout;
  fin<< "5"  << endl;
  fin<< "2012019874\tZooadan Legeaf Coaa\tFemale\t65"<<endl;
  fin<< "1111090909\tZuilia Perez\tFemale\t701"      <<endl;
  fin<< "2012019109\tProadan Legeaf Coaa\tFemale\t65"<<endl;
  fin<< "2345019176\tTrroadan Legeaf\tFemale\t98"    <<endl;
  fin<< "2012019109\tAAroadan Legeaf Coaa\tFemale\t65"<<endl;


  int x; 
  fin >> x; //this is the first number within ...   
  row *rows=new row[x];
  for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
  {
    getline(fin, rows[i].ID,   '\t'); // ID
    getline(fin, rows[i].name, '\t'); // name
    getline(fin, rows[i].rest      ); 
  }
  std::sort(rows,rows+x);
  fout << x << std::endl;
  for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
      fout<<rows[i]; 
  delete []rows;
  cout<<"Input:\n"<< fin.str()<<"\nOutput:\n"<< fout.str();     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited my code in line with what you recommended but I am having trouble with the alphabetical ordering.
I keep getting a complier error (expected primary expression before [ token) for the following line:
std::sort(rows,rows+x,[](const row& r1, const row& r2)  

For the next line, it is also a problem that "r1 was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Do you have C++11? You need it for lambdas. Did you #include <algorithm>  ? Take a look at: http://ideone.com/8OQ5mo  .If  the problem persist post your new code (in another question?) or test it in Ideone too and send me a link.

Comment: See the new variants. Ask if you dont understand.